# Remove unnecessary child elements in xml (php)

Tags: php, xml

І have the xml file and it has such structure:

```html
    <section>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    Some text
    <section>
    <title>Title 2</title>
    Some text
    <section>
    <title>Title 3</title>
    Some text
    </section>
    </section>
    </section>
```

I need to remove all internall child elements **section**, except primary elements, without changing texts. Final result must be:

```html
    <section>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    Some text
    <title>Title 2</title>
    Some text
    <title>Title 3</title>
    Some text
    </section>
```

I used SimpleXML and i accept such code:

```
foreach ($xml->body->children() as $section) {
$section = $section->asXML();

$section = strip_tags($section, '<title>');

}
```

But there is a problem, i dont know how to return the code in object xml after treatment of every element.

Comment: Your expected result does not have "all child elements removed" it still has the title elements. You need to specify what do you think is a 'primary' element. DOM+Xpath would be my suggestion because you can manipulate the node structure with it.

Comment: title must have. Must be removed only **section**.